# ANTLR : no viable alternative error

Tags: antlr, parser-generator

I have a task to write simple parser-generator, so I wrote ANTLR-like grammar and tried to parse simple file like "foo:bar;", but got the following output:

```
[@0,0:2='foo',<1>,1:0]
[@1,3:3=':',<16>,1:3]
[@2,4:6='bar',<1>,1:4]
[@3,7:7=';',<18>,1:7]
[@4,8:7='<EOF>',<-1>,1:8]
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'foo'
(rule foo : bar ;)
```

My grammar looks like

```
grammar parsGen;

gram : rule SEMICOLON (NEWLINE+ rule SEMICOLON)* ;

rule : lRule | pRule ;

lRule : LRULEID COLON lRule1 ;
lRule1 : (((LRULEID | STRING | SET) | LBRACE lRule1 PIPE lRule1 RBRACE) modificator? SPACE+)+ ;

pRule : PRULEID COLON pRule1 ;
pRule1 : (((LRULEID | PRULEID) | LBRACE lRule1 PIPE lRule1 RBRACE) modificator? SPACE+)+ ;

modificator : PLUS | ASTERISK | QUESTION ;

ID : LRULEID | PRULEID ;

LRULEID : UPPERLETTER (UPPERLETTER | LOWERLETTER | DIGIT)* ;
PRULEID : LOWERLETTER (UPPERLETTER | LOWERLETTER | DIGIT)* ;

STRING : ('\''.*?'\'') ;
SET : '\''.*?'\'..\''.*?'\'' ;

UPPERLETTER : [A-Z] ;
LOWERLETTER : [a-z] ;
DIGIT : [0-9] ;

NEWLINE : '\r\n'|'\n'|'\r' ;

PLUS : '+' ;
ASTERISK : '*' ;
QUESTION : '?' ;

LBRACE : '(' ;
RBRACE : ')' ;

SPACE : ' ' ;

COLON : ':' ;

PIPE : '|' ;

SEMICOLON : ';' ;
```

So where could I make a mistake? I tried to search everywhere (google, SO etc.) error "no viable alternative", but it didn't really help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ANTLR lexers fully assign unambiguous token types before the parser is ever used. When multiple token types can match a token, the first one appearing in the grammar is the one that is used. For your grammar, a token cannot have the type `ID` and the type `LRULEID` at the same time. Since the input `foo` matches both of these lexer rules, the first appearing in the grammar is used so your tokens are: `ID`, `COLON`, `ID`, `SEMICOLON`, `<EOF>`.

Since the `ID` token is never actually referenced in the parser, I suggest one of the following changes. *Either* of these options will resolve the problem you have described, so the choice is entirely your preference for how the final grammar looks.

**Foreword**

You need to change the space references from `SPACE+` to `SPACE*`, or the rule will *require* at least one space character between `bar` and `;`.

**Option 1**

Remove the `ID` lexer rule altogether.

**Option 2**

1. Change `ID` to a parser rule so it's not trying to assign token type `ID` to all of your identifiers.

   ```
   id : LRULEID | PRULEID;
   ```
2. Update `pRule1` rule by referencing `id`.

   ```
   pRule1 : ((id | LBRACE lRule1 PIPE lRule1 RBRACE) modificator? SPACE+)+ ;
   ```

**Unrelated Side Note**

You grammar might be easier to read if you remove the outermost `+` closure inside the `lRule` and `pRule1` rules, and instead add them to the rule references themselves, like this. Note that I changed the `SPACE` references as described in the foreword.

```
lRule : LRULEID COLON lRule1+ ;
lRule1 : ((LRULEID | STRING | SET) | LBRACE lRule1 PIPE lRule1 RBRACE) modificator? SPACE* ;

pRule : PRULEID COLON pRule1+ ;
pRule1 : ((LRULEID | PRULEID) | LBRACE lRule1 PIPE lRule1 RBRACE) modificator? SPACE* ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Also from the http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/NoViableAltException.html:

> Indicates that the parser could not decide which of two or more paths to take based upon the remaining input. It tracks the starting token of the offending input and also knows where the parser was in the various paths when the error [occured].

In my case I was calling **lexer.nextToken()** before parsing for debugging purposes. That in turn without **lexer.reset()** was causing *no viable alternative at input EOF* error.